# How do I directly turn an array of pixels into an image with PIL in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

So I remember doing this before, and stupidly I can't find my code again. I extract my array from a png like so:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.open('img1.png', 'r')
width, height = im.size

val= list(im.getdata())
```

But then I want to change a few pixels manually.

```
val[100] = (0,255,0,255)
```

I though that before there was then a way to simply create an image again using the updated list.
I've found 'Image.fromarray()' but it wants an array not a list and I can't get it to work.

I'm certain that before, it was so easy and there was some way to edit single pixels in the list and put them back into an image using
`img.save("editedimg.png")`

Anyone know what it could be that I need to use?
I would really appreciate the help, and I will be backing up my code next time!

Comment: Why not just leave the `im.getdata` result as an array and work with it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really great question past me. Let me answer that for you.

I found this finally.

You are wanting the 'putdata()' function. Add these lines after changing the val list:

```
im2 = Image.new(im.mode, im.size)
im2.putdata(val)
im2.save('new.png')
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for saving me the 10 hours I might otherwise have spent looking for the answer. 